# AMD A6 Processor, Radeon HD 8400, Laptop: Ubuntu running slow

Tags: 14.04, games, radeon

I have recently installed Ubuntu. I had done some research about switching to Ubuntu and if its worth it. It seemed pretty convincing that Ubuntu was a great OS and is better than Windows 8, the OS I had before I switched to Ubuntu. I downloaded and installed Ubuntu and it booted up fine. I installed Updates, AMD drivers for the System, and Etc . I then proceeded to go on to Fire Fox and I noticed it was very slow on getting on to Fire Fox, It took about 10 seconds. I then went to install some things, Mine craft and Java,to run it.I then logged in and It was very laggy. I ran at 50 FPS+ in Windows 8 and now I was running at 15-25 Fps. I then went on the internet to go and play a few mini games online and those were lagging too! It was lagging on Non-Intense apps also. I then thought it just needed a break for the night. I shut it down and the next day it was the same.

Specs: AMD A6 Processor, Radeon HD 8400, 4GB DDR3 Ram, 512 GB Hard Drive. (HP Laptop)

I have tried to search up a remedy to this problem but no problem had been alike to mine.

At a loss, I have resorted to a forum in hopes I can have my problem fixed.

-Gabe

Answer (score 0):

AMD releases new Catalyst 14.9 driver with support for Ubuntu 10.14 Utopic

http://www.tuxwatch.com/2014/09/amd-releases-new-catalyst-149-driver.html

Comment: Bad link - try the direct one from AMD http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/embedded?os=Linux+x86&rev=13.151

Answer (score 0):

I had an HP laptop with much the same problem.  I replaced it with an All-In-One, hoping that would make a difference.  It didn't.  There are various threads about changing the video drivers.  I tried to do that and I'm not sure if I succeeded, but in any event the problem remains.  So I'm returning the machine to Amazon, where I bought it.  I don't know if the Windows graphics performance is any better, since I have no good way to evaluate it.